# SML/NJ Error. Finished with exit code 1

Tags: smlnj

I'm trying to do the following, but the compiler exits with code 1.

```
exception InvalidCharacter

fun order (_, _, nil) = nil 
    | order(b:char list, l::xl::xxl, s::xs) = if s=l then length(l::xl::xxl)::(order (b, b, xs))
else order(b, xl::xxl, s::xs)
    | order (_, nil, _) = raise InvalidCharacter;

order ([#"a",#"b", #"c", #"d", #"e"],[#"a",#"b", #"c", #"d", #"e"],[#"b", #"e"]);
```

And the compiler also gives the match nonexhaustive for this function. I can't understand why.

Comment: It looks like you haven't matched the case where the middle argument has exactly one element.

Comment: @DavidYoung Ohh! I see now! Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the middle argument, you have just matched the cases where the list has at least two arguments and when it is empty. You also need a match for when the list has exactly one element.